# Visual Studio build folder hierarchy

Tags: visual-studio, hierarchy

I want VS to create subfolders in release directory with some linked files from project. Something like this:

```
Project/
-bin/
--Relase/
---program.exe
---Resources/
----input.txt
---Config/
----default.conf
```

How can I do this while having files "input.txt" and "default.conf" in solution hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, it's easy: just place needed items inside project in solution explorer and in properties window change property "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer" .

Comment: This works well for manually added assets, but how would i do this for the myriad of .dll and .xml files that are added to the build output when i use Nuget?